# how to give space between two buttons in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm using two buttons in my application which is been used inside a method separately.but i'm not able to given enough space between those two buttons,can someone look into it please.

here's my code:

```
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              FlutterLogo(size: 150),
              SizedBox(height: 50),
              _signInButton(),
              _signInFbButton()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _signInButton() {


    return Container(
      child: OutlineButton(
        splashColor: Colors.grey,
        onPressed: () {
          signInWithGoogle().whenComplete(() {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return FirstScreen();
                },
              ),
            );
          });
        },
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
        highlightElevation: 0,
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image(image: AssetImage("Assets/google_logo.png"), height: 35.0),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    child: Text(
                      'Sign in with Google',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.grey,



  }
  Widget _signInFbButton() {


    return Container(
      child: OutlineButton(
        splashColor: Colors.grey,
        onPressed: () {
          signInWithGoogle().whenComplete(() {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return FirstScreen();
                },
              ),
            );
          });
        },
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
        highlightElevation: 0,
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
        child: Container(
          child: Padding(

            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image(image: AssetImage("Assets/facebook-logo.png"), height: 35.0),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                      child: Text(
                        'Sign in with Google',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.grey,
```

Here's my screenshot of what im trying to do i'm creating a sign in page using google sign-in and facebook sign-in

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you try what you have already? the `SizedBox` to achieve that,

```
_signInButton(),
 SizedBox(height: 16),//<----
_signInFbButton()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap `_signInFbButton()` widget with `Padding` and provide top padding per your requirement. Working code below:

```
_signInButton(),
              Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
              child: _signInFbButton())
```

[image]

Hope this answers your question.